# EM algorithm special case

Tags: expectation-maximization, bayes-factors

I'm considering a collection of Bayes Factors, $\mbox{BF}(j)$, $j=1, ..., J$, so that the overall evidence against $H_0$ is represented by the overall Bayes Factor
 $$\frac{P(x|H_0 \mbox{ false})}{P(x | H_0 \mbox{ true})} = \sum_{j=1}^{J} w_j \mbox{BF}(j)\,,$$ 
where $\sum_{j=1}^Jw_j = 1$.

I now have access to a restricted set data from which I would like to estimate the optimal weights $w_j$: I can to compute the Bayes Factors $\mbox{BF}_i{(j)}$ for each observation $i=1, ..., n$ and for each $j=1, ..., J$, and I can form:
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{J} w_j \mbox{BF}_i(j)\,.$$

So the problem consists in finding weights that maximize this expression. I was wondering if we could consider this as a likelihood and compute a sort of EM algorithm, similar to that used for Gaussian mixtures.
However, as far as I understand, since I already have the $\mbox{BF}_i(j)$ computed, I wouldn't need to optimize the means and variances for each mixture(?)
...and in this case, I don't see how to apply the EM algorithm anymore.

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me on this.

Is the EM approach a good option? If yes, how exactly should I apply it? If no, is there a simple other strategies that guaranties $0 \leq w_j \leq 1$ $\forall j$ and $\sum_{j=1}^Jw_j = 1$ ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand the rationale for an average of Bayes factors. Is there any case this is equal to a true Bayes factor? Can you provide an illustration when this naturally occurs? Thank you.

Comment: Without going into too much detail, in my case, $j$ represents a partition of a set of variables involved in the model into different functions: some are directly associated with the quantity of interest, some are indirectly associated with it and finally, some are not associated. Here, the average is over all possible partitions and represents the overall evidence against the null ($H_0$: all the variables are unassociated).

Comment: The denominator is the same for all Bayes Factors. It corresponds to the global null hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat the function to maximise$$\prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{J} w_j \mbox{BF}_i(j)$$as a pseudo-likelihood, this likelihood is a formal mixture where only the weights $w_j$ are unknown. Hence you can apply EM for that purpose (of finding a local optimum). The algorithm is as follows:

1. Start with an arbitrary value of $\mathbf{w}^{(0)}=(w_1,\ldots,w_J)$
2. Given the current value of the parameter $\mathbf{w}^{(t)}$, derive the expectations (E) of the latent variables $z_{ij}$ as$$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{w}^{(t)}}[Z_{ij}|x_i]=\dfrac{w_j^{(t)}BF_i(j)}{\sum_{k=1}^J w_j^{(t)}BF_i(j)}$$
3. Update the weights from $\mathbf{w}^{(t)}$ to $\mathbf{w}^{(t)}$ as
   $$w_j^{(t+1)}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{w}^{(t)}}[Z_{ij}|x_i]}{\sum_{k=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{w}^{(t)}}[Z_{ik}|x_i]}$$
4. Increase $t$ to $t+1$ and get back to Step 2. unless $\mathbf{w}^{(t)}=\mathbf{w}^{(t)}$

The justification for this representation comes from writing the mixture$$ \sum_{j=1}^{J} w_j \mbox{BF}_i(j)$$as the marginal of$$w_j^{z_{ij}} \mbox{BF}_i(j)^{z_{ij}}$$where $\mathbf{z_i}=(z_{i1},\ldots,z_{iJ})$ is a multinomial $\mathcal{M}(1;\mathbf{w})$, i.e. with only one component equal to one and all others equal to zero.

Comment: (+1) The EM algorithm here has nothing to do with a Gaussian density, it is merely an optimisation algorithm. The $BF_i(j)$ are numbers that we interpret as values of densities to apply EM, but even the normalisation you mention makes no sense because there is no reason whatsoever the Bayes factor is integrable in the observation... I said "pseudo" in that sense that we use an algorithm originally designed for a mixture of densities towards a different purpose, if with the same validation.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Your help was more than useful. The algorithm is implemented and converges quickly towards what seems to be a global maximum (several starting points tested). Thank you very much!